# JSON: Response not coming over

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am hoping someone can help with this, I've a form ***signup.php*** with ajax that POST to another page ***register.php***. I am unable to get the json response from the function that's called in the ***register.php*** file.  I encoded the result from the function in the register.php file `echo json_encode($register)` but nothing is showing up when the registration completes. I have debugger setup on the browser to follow the network responses, for some reason header content-type is text/html not sure if that's the problem.

What I am trying to do is on success show the response from the function, but it's not working. Here are my current code.

***signup.php***

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#submit").click(function()
        {
            var formData = $("#signup").serializeArray();
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../pages/register.php",
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: formData,
                        success: function(response) {
                            $('#message').html(response);
                        }
                    });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
        <h1>Carelincs</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <form action="" method="POST" id="signup">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="eMail"/>
            <br />
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name"/>
            <br />
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
            <br />
            <label for="confirm password">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="repeatpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <p id="message"></p>
        <div data-role="popup" id="validate" class="">  
            <p>Account created! Activation email has been sent, check your email.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***register.php***

```
<?php


require_once("../auth/config.class.php");
require_once("../auth/auth.class.php");

$config = new Config;

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $config-> dbhost . ";dbname=" . $config->dbname,  $config->dbuser, $config->dbpass);


$auth = new Auth($dbh, $config);



$email = $_POST["email"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$repeatpassword = $_POST["repeatpassword"];




$register = $auth->register($email, $username, $password, $repeatpassword ); 


// Temporary just so you can see what's going on :

echo json_encode($register); 
?>
```

Comment: What does `response` contain, have you done a `console.log(response);`? If it's an object, you can't use it like that in `.html()`.

Comment: Try `header('Content-Type: application/json')` before outputting your JSON since the AJAX method is going to be looking for it since you explicitly said you expected it: `dataType: 'json',`.

Comment: Also check for 'error' in the AJAX call. If you had something that can't be translated as JSON, jQuery calls the function in error. console.log() that one too.

Comment: @cillosis explicitly defining the data type means that the server does **not** have to sent a content type header.

Comment: @jeroen this is what response contains and it shows up on the response body `{"code":200,"message":"register_success"}`

Comment: The information been returned is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the data, you have to access the strings of the object:

so for your case you can change the tag to a `div`

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

and then parse the json data in that div

```
 $('#message').html('<p> code: ' + response.code + '</p>');
 $('#message').append('<p> message: ' + response.message+ '</p>');
```